# Disable values in a DropDownList

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist where I select names of people. But I need to disable used values because I want to have two of the same value in the same id of an event... In the database I fixed the issue using compoud keys but I need to solve this programmatically.

This is my shorter data source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:fotbalConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT table1.ID_person, table1.ID_event,FROM [table1] WHERE ([ID_event] = @ID_event)        
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:QueryStringParameter 
            DefaultValue="0" 
            Name="ID_event" 
            QueryStringField="id" 
            Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a **hash** whose **keys will be the identifiers** of values you have in the dropDownList and the **values will be a boolean** which will indicate if it has been used.

You will need a method to **update** the Hash, so everytime you select some item from the DDL (dropDownList) you mark it as used or not (if it's the case). You can call this method from SelectedIndexChanged event.

Also will need a method to **list** values (key) from the Hash for your DDL where you just get unselected (value == false) items.

The property where you store data could have a getter like this:

```
private Hashtable SelectedValuesHash        
{
        get
        {
            object o = ViewState["SelectedValuesHash"];

            if (o == null)
                return new Hashtable();
            else
                return (Hashtable)o;
        }
    }
```

The method to add values could be like this:

```
 private void AddSelectedValuesToHash(int key, bool hasBeenSelected)
    {
        var rows = ViewState["SelectedValuesHash"] as Hashtable;

        if (rows == null)
        {
            rows = new Hashtable();
            ViewState["SelectedValuesHash"] = rows;
        }
        rows.Add(key, hasBeenSelected);
    }
```

Comment: It's not, really. Apply "divide et vinces" strategy and you will realize as it's not hard at all. Create a hash, assign values to it in the event I mentioned before, and retrieve these values when listing DDL values, simple IF to list or not values and bind result to DDL. Try and if you get stucked, here we are to help you.

Comment: Now i have this: protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Collections.Hashtable ht = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
    }

Comment: Yes, that's the object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx

Comment: No, if you create the object everytime you change the selected index, how would you make the information persistant? Everytime it would be new and would erase old values. The HashTable could be a private property, you initialize it in the property getter if it's null, if not you assign new key/value. [Updated main answer with code]

Comment: yes, its true..like this:    private System.Collections.Hashtable SelectedValuesHash
    {   
            System.Collections.Hashtable ht = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
            ht.Add("value", "");
       
    }

Comment: The your SelectedValuesHash its selected value of dropdownlist,ok?

Comment: You have code for the getter property and the add method in the main answer. Now you have to edit the SelectedIndexChanged event so it adds to the hash the new selected item. After that you have to make a method which will receive the collection you were binding to DDL before (DDL.DataSource = collection) and erase from it the elements which are contained by the hash (SelectedValuesHash.ContainsKey(key))

Comment: like this: DropDownList DropDownList2 = (sender as DropDownList);
        String value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;      but this get the value to string value...but how i add to hashtable :/

Comment: Look at the main answer, I added the code for adding elements to hashtable.

Comment: protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList DropDownList2 = (sender as DropDownList);
        String SelectedValuesHash = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    }

Comment: You have the idea and some of the methods, think about it, split in smaller problems, try the solutions you reach, explore the object properties and methods with Visual Studio intellisense and if you get stucked, ask. The step by step solution is useless to learn the proper way of doing and thinking.

Comment: I try to, but it last problem in diploma work and i have very low time :/

Comment: i must save the selectedvalue to object o, ok? like this?:             protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList DropDownList2 = (sender as DropDownList);
        String o = DropDownList2.SelectedValue;
    }